# Two domains one app

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

Here's my situation: I have a facebook app that needs to do major data processing, and I need it done on another server (basically a subdomain).  However, I do not know how to access a user's "data" from the other server, unless the user authenticates with two apps.

Is there a way to prompt the user for permissions to allow their data to be processed on another server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the second server is a subdomain of your registered namespace, you should be able to use your app credentials on that machine as well. Facebook doesn't care, as long as you're not sharing your users' data with third parties.

Comment: To authenticate the user (assuming they already authenticated in my app) I only need their user id?

Comment: You'll also have to pass their `access_token` between your servers. This is what really says they are authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

if you are giving access to that subdomain on your facebook app settings, no problem to access to credentials. you can use without any problem.